# SQL combine 2 table and then update it into another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 table that I got using query from my database.

OverallTable

```
| Invoice | Product | Total | Delivered | Not Delivered |
---------------------------------------------------------
|  00001  |  AAAA   |   4   |   null    |     null      |
|  00001  |  BBBB   |   2   |   null    |     null      |
|  00001  |  CCCC   |   2   |   null    |     null      |
|  00002  |  AAAA   |   3   |   null    |     null      |
```

*OverallTable on initial state

DeliveredTable

```
| Invoice | Product | Delivered |
---------------------------------
|  00001  |  AAAA   |     2     |
|  00001  |  BBBB   |     2     |
|  00001  |  CCCC   |     0     |
|  00002  |  AAAA   |     3     |
```

NotDeliveredTable

```
| Invoice | Product | Not Delivered |
---------------------------------
|  00001  |  AAAA   |      2        |
|  00001  |  BBBB   |      0        |
|  00001  |  CCCC   |      2        |
|  00002  |  AAAA   |      0        |
```

The question is how do i insert the delivered and undelivered data into OverallTable?

I try to update using the following query, but I get error

> Subquery returned more than 1 value

```
UPDATE @OverallTemp
SET delivered = 
(SELECT ddt.fqty FROM @DeliveredTemp ddt where ddt.PRODUCT= 
[@OverallTemp].product)
WHERE EXISTS 
(SELECT ddt.invoice FROM @DeliveredTemp ddt where ddt.invoice= 
[@OverallTemp].invoice);

UPDATE @OverallTemp
SET notdelivered = 
(SELECT sdt.qty FROM @NotDeliveredTemp sdt  where sdt.PRODUCT= 
[@OverallTemp].product)
WHERE EXISTS 
(SELECT sdt.invoice FROM @NotDeliveredTemp sdt where sdt.invoice= 
[@OverallTemp].invoice);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't to use `EXISTS`, just do the `JOIN` with `UPDATE` statement :

```
UPDATE ot
     set ot.Delivered = dt.Delivered 
FROM OverallTable ot INNER JOIN 
     DeliveredTable dt 
     ON dt.Invoice = ot.Invoice AND
        dt.Product = ot.Product;
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you the problem here, your sub query returned more than 1 row.

If you want to `INSERT` data into table using a dataset, then you need to treat that data like a dataset, not a scalar value:

For example, for your first attempt, the correct query would be (note this is untesed):

```
UPDATE OT
SET delivered = ddt.fqty
FROM @OverallTemp OT
     JOIN  @DeliveredTemp ddt ON ddt.PRODUCT= OT.product;
```

Have a go at the second query, and if you have trouble, please do comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `UPDATE ...From  ... JOIN` instead of the update subquery.

```
update t1
set Delivered = t2.Delivered 
from OverallTable t1
join DeliveredTable t2 on t2.Invoice = t1.Invoice 
and  t2.Product = t1.Product 

update t1
set [Not Delivered] = t2.[Not Delivered]
from  NotDeliveredTable t1
join NotDeliveredTable t2 on t2.Invoice  = t1.Invoice
 and  t2.Product = t1.Product
```

Comment: These don't make sense. you're setting the value of the `delivered` to `o.delivered`, which is the alias you have used for the table you are updating (hence you won't change anything). Also, the  columsn to OP is using from the other tables are `ddt.fqty` and `sdt.qty` respectively.

Comment: What is `t2`? There is no object with that alias.  However, I would go back to your old aliases: [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Comment: @Larnu The question is why is called the error. the answer might `Update ... join`, I know the alias name is bad but I think the question isn' t about the alias name